# “She's a pass” meaning

Tags: meaning

There is a song titled “She's a pass” by Paul Leonard-Morgan (“Dredd” OST).

What does “a pass” mean? I've read the whole definition from Merriam-Webster, but still not sure.

Comment: It's an instrumental track with no lyrics for context, so this is simply a case of guessing what was in the writer's head.

Comment: @KillingTime Hi, I think the movie is the context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scene from the movie ([Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-VFsXrYvmo)) makes it fairly obvious.

The core of the story is the assessment of the rookie-Judge Anderson. At the end, Dredd is asked if she passed or failed the assessment.

He replies "She's a pass", just before the music starts.

Comment: So the film explains itself, and we couldn't.

Comment: This may be an explanation of what was intended by the sentence, but it doesn't explain why the formulation chosen was 'She **is** a pass', rather than, as would be more usual, 'She passed [the test]'?